# Where are the database files queried by dpkg-query?

Tags: dpkg

I don't see where are the database files checked by `dpkg-query -S` in its manpage. Could anybody let me know where it is? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It depends upon exactly what kind of query you do, but all of `dpkg`'s database files are under `/var/lib/dpkg`. They are often plain text files.

For example, a simple `dpkg-query -l` will find what it needs in `/var/lib/dpkg/status`:

```
$ strace -e trace=open,openat dpkg-query -l base-files
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/lib/dpkg/arch", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/lib/dpkg/status", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/dpkg.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/dpkg.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/dpkg.mo", O_RDONLY) = 4
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale-langpack/en/LC_MESSAGES/dpkg.mo", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/lib/dpkg/updates/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/Unincorp", O_RDONLY) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/tty", O_RDONLY)  = 4
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache", O_RDONLY) = 4
||/ Name              Version       Architecture  Description
+++-=================-=============-=============-=======================================
ii  base-files        10.1ubuntu2.1 amd64         Debian base system miscellaneous files
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

**Update: Question has been changed from simple `dpkg-query` to specify `dpkg-query -S`**. So to answer that:

As mentioned, exactly where `dpkg-query` looks depends upon what type of query you do, but all of its information exists below `/var/lib/dpkg/`. For `dpkg-query -S` queries for example, it examines every `*.list` file in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/`:

```
$ strace -e trace=open,openat dpkg-query -S /bin/ls 
[…]
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/lib/dpkg/info/fonts-sil-abyssinica.list", O_RDONLY) = 4
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/lib/dpkg/info/libatk-adaptor:amd64.list", O_RDONLY) = 4
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/lib/dpkg/info/libvorbisfile3:amd64.list", O_RDONLY) = 4
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/lib/dpkg/info/libquadmath0:amd64.list", O_RDONLY) = 4
[…]
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/lib/dpkg/info/tzdata.list", O_RDONLY) = 4                             
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/lib/dpkg/diversions", O_RDONLY) = 4                                   
coreutils: /bin/ls                                                                           
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Comment: I tried the strace for apt-file. `strace -e trace=open,openat apt-file search /usr/bin/lshw-gtk`. But I don't see which file has the apt database. Which files has the apt database? Thanks.

Comment: Your question was about ```dpkg-query```, not ```apt```.If this answer does answer your question about ```dpkg-query``` then please mark it as answered.  If you still have a question about ```apt``` then it would be best asked in a new question post.

Comment: No. Even for dpkg, it shows so many files. You did not answer what files are the database files.

Comment: I literally wrote that for your specific query the file is ```/var/lib/dpkg/status```. That was the third sentence of my answer. Then I showed output where that file appears. It is at the 6th line of the code block. I don't know how to make this any clearer.

Comment: Every time when you run dpkg, will it be updated? I am asking the original databases file that dpkg query not some intermediate files. Also, I have made  the command to be specific to `dpkg-query -S`

Comment: Answer updated for ```dpkg-query -S```. All of ```dpkg```'s data files are below ```/var/lib/dpkg/```. It reads and modifies those files in the course of its operation. That is the primary source of truth about ```dpkg```.